Having trouble finding the midpoint for animate transform
Got an svg spinning but its not centered
<html>
    <body>



        <svg width="35px" height="50px">
         
        
        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1 1 750 730">
    
        <g>
             <path d="m375,0l-108.48,159.39-192.25-14.56,56.98,184.19L0,470.24l179.53,70.29,28.58,190.67,166.89-96.54,166.89,96.54,28.58-190.67,179.53-70.29-131.25-141.23,56.98-184.19-192.25,14.56L375,0Z"/>
            
           <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 480 450" to="360 30 450" dur="8.8s" additive="sum" repeatCount="indefinite" />
       
        
        </g>
       
           <use transform="matrix(10, 1,10, 1, 20, 10)" href="#star1">
          </use>
        </svg>
        
    </body>
</html>

Ive been endlessly making the numbers larger and smaller from="0 480 450" to="360 30 450

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You HTML doesn't seem valid, you have two opening <svg> tags and only one closing tag.

If i am not wrong you are looking for spinner in center of the body. For that you need to use CSS for that.


<html>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <svg width="100px" height="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1 1 750 730">
        <g>
            <path d="m375,0l-108.48,159.39-192.25-14.56,56.98,184.19L0,470.24l179.53,70.29,28.58,190.67,166.89-96.54,166.89,96.54,28.58-190.67,179.53-70.29-131.25-141.23,56.98-184.19-192.25,14.56L375,0Z"/>
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 375 375" to="360 375 375" dur="8.8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>



